# How to render a page following a GET request node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on express js and a particular endpoint renders the page using

```
res.render('dialog',{state:'admin'});
```

This endpoint is at http://localhost:3000/api/login. When i open this link in the browser, it opens the dialog.ejs page but when i call this endpoint using a GET request from another part of the server, the dialog.ejs page is not rendered

```
request({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/login',
    headers:{
      'Authorization' : auth
    }, 
    method: 'GET'
}, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log("Response to request for authorization code : " + response.statusCode);
});
```

Please help !

Comment: check the body in request() call for ex. console.log(err, response, body) body is the output of call.

Comment: I have done console.log(body), i got the contents of the ejs file :                          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Beer Locker</title>
  </head><body> <p>Hi nik!</p>
    <p><b>alexa</b> is requesting <b>full access</b> to your account.</p>
    <p>Do you approve?</p>
    <form action="/api/oauth2/authorize" method="post">
      <input name="transaction_id" type="hidden" value="ZHXSJ1Ct">
      <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Allow" id="allow">
      <input type="submit" value="Deny" name="cancel" id="deny">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: which means you are getting modal html correctly in the response from request() also.

Comment: @user3655266 This is the correct behaviour. What do you expect to happen or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, but the page isn't redirecting to this ejs file, i am new to express, please help !

Comment: the request you are sending from another part is not user request, i mean its implicite request to face it to user, you need to redirect instead of calling route from inside server

Comment: How can i do a redirect ?

Comment: to redirect use res.redirect()

Comment: Remove all your request code and instead put: res.redirect('/api/login')

Comment: I also need to pass headers, i have edited the code, please have a look

Comment: I am new to express js , so can some please help me out. Is something wrong with my question, i don't understand why i am getting downvotes

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you build a handmade request chances are that you're missing half of the headers the browser is sending, so that can be one of the reasons the whole thing is failing

On the other, if your making a machine to machine request, you DON'T want the ejs page renders, You only need to recover the neeeded data and /or make the server do something "**as you were login in from a browser**".

And as you're including the authorization Header, you're probably trying to simulate a login or authorization of some kind ( maybe a JWT Token ?)

Any case i think oyour only options is to mimic what your browser do as far as possible . So Build a perfectly correct set of headers, inject what will 
be the result of form data, probably url_encoded, and use the correct request method (GET is perfectly correct, but coming from an html from POST is much more common. check it)

Just only one suggestion. Rendering a full web page from an /api/login seems a bit incorrect. Usually Api enpoints talk JSON only. In and out